# OnResume called multiple times inside fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, onresume, fragmentmanager

I have **InnerFragment** containing RecyclerView, inside **MainFragment** which is added to **ViewPager**. 
When MainFragment gets created while swiping OnResume is called multiple times

- 1st time : OnResume called once in MainFragment and Once in InnerFragment
- 2n time : OnResume called once in MainFragment and Twice in InnerFragment
- 3rd time : OnResume called once in MainFragment and Thrice in InnerFragment

**Adding MainFragment in ViewPager**

```
//Assigning Adapter in ViewPager
mViewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getFragmentManager()));
//getItem inside MyAdaper
public Fragment getItem(int position){
    return MainFragment.newInstance(position);
}
```

**Adding InnerFragment in MainFragment**

```
getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.framelayoutID, InnerFragment.newInstance()).commit();
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

when adding fragment, use **replace()** instead of **add()**

**before**

```
getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.framelayoutID, InnerFragment.newInstance()).commit();
```

**after**

```
getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.framelayoutID, InnerFragment.newInstance()).commit();
```

Comment: accepting my own answer because it worked for me and, may be helpful for others as well.